# Change input value after click on list element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got form with input

```
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <input type="search"
                               onChange={handleChange}
                               onFocus={() => setFocus({name: true})}
                               onBlur={() => setFocus({name: false})}
                               value={inputName}
                        />
       </form>
```

and the `list` of elements which is rendered after this input field has `focus`. This input field is live searcher for elements of this rendered `list`.

the code to render list:

```
<div>
      {
           objects.map((object, index) => {
                 return (
                   <ul>
                          <li key={index}>
                                {object.name}
                          </li>
                   </ul>
                )
           })
       }
</div>
```

I want to make the action that when I click on the `list` element, the `input` field gets this element value.
In the picture below, the input field should be `Object 2` after I click on `Object 2` element

[image]

Due to there are two independent `jsx` objects, I have no idea how can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do this with a function triggered `onClick` on a `<li>` that sets the `inputName` value with the `object.name` :

```
<div>
<ul>
      {
           objects.map((object, index) => {
                 return (
                   
                          <li key={index} onClick={() => setInputName(object.name)}>
                                {object.name}
                          </li>
                   
                )
           })
       }
</ul>
</div>
```

And by the way I think your `<ul>` tag should be outside the `map`

Comment: I think the above would help. Just try to find some other property as key. Key as index is a bad [practice](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: yes I don't know what the object look like, if there's a property id, he can do ```key={object.id}```